# IOS - Split long NSString into NSArray based on current framesize and use pages in UIPageControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, uipagecontrol

I am struggling to find an algorithm that can split long NSString into NSArray based on screen size. I am trying to implement UIPageControl and need to split text across pages.

I have tried implementing NSTextContainer and setting frame size there but did't find a way to calculate how much NSTextContainers should be added into NSLayoutManager to cover whole string.

Any help on the algorithm or any suggestion on NSTextContainer to split text across pages will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So are you trying to reinvent Text Kit, or one of the other text layout systems provided by Apple?

Comment: Not really, I am just trying to understand how to achieve this using TextKit or CoreText.

Comment: https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios7-day-by-day-day-21-multi-column-textkit-text-rendering